# I am not calling max -- but the C++ compiler in xcode is saying no matching function for call to max

Tags: c++, xcode

I am new to C++. In xcode 5, this line of code is throwing the error, "no matching function for call to max." But I'm not calling max! What's going on?

```
springfact += clamp (0, ff.compression - 0.05, 0.12) * 3000; //no matching function for call to max
```

Answer (score 1):

`clamp()` calls `max()`. From its documentation, `clamp` takes a minimum and a maximum value and "clamps" the `value` parameter between it, so it most likely is implemented like this:

```
clamp(min_value,value,max_value) -> min(max(min_value,value),max_value)
```

The error message is pointing you to the line you see because `clamp` is probably implemented as a macro but for some reason `max` is not declared/defined.

Comment: Look for where clamp is declared in your header file(s).  Add that to the post, and you will probably have your answer.